# Http redirection in angular 4 with http header changes

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, xmlhttprequest, angular4-httpclient

Angular 4 is used with Spring 4 MVC.

Below is the code in my angular service:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        .set('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*');
let params = new HttpParams().set('noCache', new Date().getTime().toString());
let options = { headers: this.getHeadersForCDRedirection(), params: params };
let url = 'abc.htm';

httpClient.get(url,options); // httpClient: HttpClient injected in constructor
```

In the back end, set response headers as below for redirection:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "abc.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody MyBean myMethod(){
    // code
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
    String redirectURL = "pqr.htm";
    response.setHeader("Location", redirectUrl);
    // code
    return bean;
}
```

I am facing the issue highlighted in below git bug:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18396

however, Am not able to implement the workaround suggested in the link. Appreciate your inputs on the approach to be followed.

Comment: use 
let options = { headers: this.getHeadersForCDRedirection(), params: params, responseType: 'text' };

Comment: @KAMRULHASANSHAHED, I had tried it earlier. Dint work then. However, it's working on. Thanks.